# (On a mac) - VirtualBox not able to access the .vmdk file for a usb virtual machine

Tags: macos, command-line, virtualbox, virtual-machine, terminal.app

When selecting my virtual disk in virtualbox, the error reads as in the photo.

[image: The error]

I have done this successfully while "sudo -b"-ing the executable in the app, but I need the file to be under my user.